# Bluez 5.28 - Transport endpoint is not connected (107)

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluez

I am using bluez 5.28 on the raspberry pi. If I want to connect to a bluetooth le peripheral with a mac-address that not exists, after 20 seconds following error occurs: "connect error: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)“.
I think that is the correct behaviour.

I my case, I need to reduce the 20 seconds timeout to a lower value. 
My question is, where can I change this timeout?
Is it defined in the bluez package, or somewhere else?

Comment: Are you creating a progam of some sort? And it so in what language? It is quite easy to add a timer to any programming language that cuts out after a certain time if no MAC address is found. @Steff

Comment: Yes, i am creating a program in C to connect to a list of bluetooth devices, to proof their attendance. Therefore it is bad, if the program waits 20 seconds if one device is not connectable. 
How can I add a timer in C to cut out?